# How to set the value of DropdownButton inside showDialog() method in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set the value of the drop down menu inside showDialog() method, but since it's not in in build method I can't set the state of the current value. So is there a solution for this?
Here's my code

```
showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          actions: [
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Cancel'
                )),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: FONT_BODY_TEXT.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0),
                )),
          ],
          content: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Select your new item',
                ),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: _item,
                  hint: Text(
                    'Select an item',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _item = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: MYLIST.map((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(
                        value,
                        style: FONT_BODY_TEXT,
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

I need to get the new item from this method so I can submit the changes, that's why I am using showDialog() method so whenever I click on submit, the item is returned, and whenver I click on cancel it will not return an item. This is just for confirmation of the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StatefulBuilder to use setState inside Dialog and update Widgets only inside of it.

```
              StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                  return DropdownButton<String>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: item,
                    hint: Text(
                      'Select an item',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (newValue) => {
                      setState(() {
                        item = newValue;
                      })
                    },
                    items: ['A', 'B', 'c'].map((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                }),
```